# program.exe stops working after compiling?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code to obtain a patch/sub_window of an array. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int patch(int a[5][5],int b[2][2],int r,int s)
{

int i=0,j=0,k;

if(r<=(5-2) && s<=(5-2)){

    for(r;r<(r+2);r++){
        for(s;s<(s+2);s++)
        {
            k = a[r][s];
            b[i][j] = k;

            i = i+1;
            j = j+1;

        }
    }
}
else
{printf("error!");}

return 0;
}

 int main()
{
int i,j,p,q;
int y[2][2] = {0};

int x[5][5] = {{95,155,200,200,232},
{100,155,232,95,150},
{200,45,200,135,123},
{232,150,85,69,180},
{95,95,200,123,45}
};

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        patch(x,y,i,j);
        for(p=0;p<2;p++){
            for(q=0;q<2;q++)
            {
                printf("y[%d][%d] = %d\n",p,q,y[p][q]);

            }
        }
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

However, once i run and compile this code I get an error stating that program.exe has stopped working. How can I fix this ? Do i need to use dynamic memory allocation for this kind of process? Or is there a simpler solution.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Did it work before compiling?

Comment: Inspect the value of the index variables `r` and `s` with respect to the dimension of the array `a`.

Comment: your for loops in patch() are never going to stop because r is always going to be less than r+2.  Same for s.  This will take you out of bounds on your array access pretty fast and probably crash your program.  Try using a temporary r and s variable in the condition check of your for loop.

Comment: I understand s and r keeps increasing, thanks guys. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
for(r;r<(r+2);r++)
```

will run for a lot longer than you intend, causing a buffer overflow. I think you mean to save `r+2` before starting the loop, and then compare against that.

Also, you will increment `i` and `j` 4 times, so you access out the bounds of `b` too. You need to re-think your loop logic. Perhaps it should be:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
    {
        b[i][j] = a[r+i][s+j];
    }
```